# Abnormal execution order in tf.function while looping through Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Given the following code snippet.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.Variable(0)

@tf.function
def f():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
    for i in dataset:
        a.assign(i)
        tf.print(a)
    tf.print(a)

f()
```

If executed in TF 2.0, the result is `1 2 3 3`.

If executed in TF 2.1, the result is `1 2 3 0`.

Why there are differences between two versions and why the second output is valid?

Comment: Using use_locking=True doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in TF 2.2.